# How do I add "active" class to dashboard menu button when visiting in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have successfully implemented this code to set a specific class to active menus when visitors are on a page. But I can't figure out how I can manage to do the same with the home page, or in other words the very first index page.

**This works on the other pages**

```
<?=($this->uri->segment(1)==='profiles')?'active':'not-active'?>
```

**Then I tried this, but that didn't work...**

```
<?=($this->uri->segment(1)==='index')?'active':'not-active'?>
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for the controller (class) and/or method instead. If you're visiting http://example.com/, then your default controller being used, but nothing is set to uri segment 1.

Codeigniter 2:

```
<?=($this->router->fetch_class()==='index')?'active':'not-active'?>
```

Codeigniter 3:

```
<?=($this->router->class==='index')?'active':'not-active'?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm actually using CodeIgniter 3 so it did work out now!